# Cross Origins advice in relation to Rest API access and end user apps

Tags: spring, rest, http-headers, cors

I am not so much in need of code help here, more advice on how I should handle this scenario.

I have a REST API built, using Spring boot.

I also have a simple Hybrid app that I need to deploy to users within the company - and clients who "buy in" to the API access. The users can be anywhere in the world, which means I never know what domain they will be on.

I am told that using the header below is bad practice :

```
"Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"*"
```

Given that I know the only point of access with our API should be this frontend app, but that I never know where the user of that app will be, or what network they will be on, how should I do this?

Tagging spring community here, even though this is not a spring centric question. This is because I am actually using Spring, and I guess that community will have solved this problem before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that this question is not about CORS exactly.

"Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"*" is OK since you need your API to be accessible from anywhere.

Even if you know all the Origins you need to allow, you should not rely on Origin header sent from the client as one can send any header.

**Authenticate your users and you'll know whether the user can access the API or not.**

Thanks.